# Replacement for Pidgin on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chat, google-apps

I need a Google Talk client for my Ubuntu. Nothing fancy, I just don't want to keep my browser open all the time. I was using Pidgin, but about two weeks ago it became extremely slow and unresponsive. I have brand new AMD APU, a lot of memory and SSD HDD on SATA III, so I don't think any hardware upgrade will be able to help. I clearly need a new client.

I was perfectly happy with Pidgin, so my question is: What software for Ubuntu is *just* like it, but made by different team (and thus unaffected by bug that hit me)?

Features I liked in Pidgin was:

- Contact list automatically synchronized with Google
- Auto-login
- Google-compatible status display
- Small, simple interface
- Hidden in an icon next to the clock (in KDE) most of the time
- **Didn't require me to know XMPP parameters of Google server**, I was able to just select Google and have it working, with no thinking on my part needed. Just user and password.

Comment: Does the client have to support voice as well, or just chat? In that case Mozilla Thunderbird would work fine

Comment: @Timmy Never used voice, to be honest. I don't know if pidgin supports it well, and I will not cry for it :)

Comment: Could you list what you mean with "just like it"? Currently, almost any XMPP client seems to be a possible solution (if they did not cancel their XMPP support completely) which is probably too broad.

Comment: @unor Done. If it's still too broad, so be it - I don't know how to make it any better, if it needs to be closed, it will. If there is anything more to add, I'll try if asked to.

Answer (score 2):

The email client [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) also has a chat service which supports Google Talk accounts. It works on Ubuntu, and it is updated frequently. So you can assume that all bugs would be addressed quickly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use Google Chrome, you can [install Hangouts from Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd).

Hangouts opens in a separate window and will continue to run even after you exit Chrome.

[image: Screenshot of Hangouts showing it running in separate windows]

Answer (score 2):

If you use KDE, you will find Telepathy is a great ready-installed choice.

The Quick Chat widgets even show the avatar of the person in chat with me (I use for Facebook, but I think it also works for Google Talk). When your conversation is closed, the icon will disappears.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you like KDE, you can use [Kopete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopete) is an excellent alternative.

Personally I advise you to use [**Empathy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empathy_%28software))

It is an instant messaging program supporting text, voice, video, file transfers and inter-application communication over many different protocols, including: AIM, MSN, Google Talk (Jabber/XMPP), Facebook, Yahoo!, Salut, Gadu-Gadu, Groupwise, ICQ and QQ.

Install in Ubuntu:

```
 sudo apt-get install empathy
```

[image]